# Why does this formula for the number of elements in a kernel hold?

Tags: group-theory

Here is the question I'm looking at:
Group $D_3$ is given by the table below:
[image]
Group ${A,*}$ is $\{0,4\}$ under addition modulo 8.
Function $f:D_3\rightarrow A$ is a group homomorphism from $D_3$ to $A$.  Find all possible kernels of $f$ and explain why there can be no others.

I found that the kernels must be $D_3$ itself and $\{e,r,s\}$.  However the book then goes onto state that

$n(ker(f))=\frac{n(D_3)}{n(\mathrm{range}(f))}$.

Why is that true?  I know about Lagrange but I still can't see the link.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\range}{\rm range}$The book is appealing to the first isomorphism theorem for groups, which says that if you have a homomorphism of groups $f : G \to H$ then the groups
$$
G/\ker(f) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \range(f)
$$
are isomorphic. If $G$ and $H$ are finite, the two groups above will have the same order, whence your formula.

Comment: Thanks.  The next chapter in the book is about isomorphisms so at this stage I wouldn't know that yet.  Is there another way to look at it or has the book made a mistake in asking this question now?

Comment: For that formula, you only need to know that there is a bijection between the set of cosets of $\ker(f)$ in $G$, and the range of $f$. Perhaps you have already seen this, otherwise it looks premature.